# Content in li is pushed to new line when present under p tag

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.class-0-653 {
color : #231f20 ; 
font-size : 1.0rem ; 
line-height : 1.2em ; 
list-style-position : inside ; 
margin-left : 4.68% ; 
margin-right : 2.44% ; 
text-indent : 5.0% ; 
}

.class-0-651 {
text-align : justify ; 
}

.class-0-622 {
color : #231f20 ; 
font-size : 1.0rem ; 
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1 style="background-color: red;">Hello World!</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<ol>
<li> Item 1 </li>
<li class="class-0-653" id="id-0-645"><p class="class-0-651" id="id-0-646"><span class="class-0-622" id="id-0-647"> Item 2 </span> </p> </li>
</ol>

</body>
</html>
```

If you run this html, the content Item2 is starting beneath the `<li>` marker, in a new line. I want it to appear besides the marker, like any usual lists. I tried various combinations in chrome inspect window and turning off `list-style-position` is fixing the issue. Similarly, if I change the `<p>` to `<span>` or if I remove the `<p>`  altogether, the issue is fixed. I am not following what influence does the `<p>` tag on the content placing. Can someone help me understand

Comment: `list-style-position : inside;` is causing the mess.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By default, `p` is a `block` element. According to [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements):

> By default, block-level elements begin on new lines, but inline elements can start anywhere in a line.

Using CSS, you can change the default property of the `<p>` tag from `block` to `inline`:

```
.class-0-651 {
      text-align : justify ;
      display: inline;   /* new */
}
```